# Whats wrong with array declaration: "invalid digit in octal constant"?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

```
int arr[20][20] = {
                    {08,02,22,97,38,15,00,40,00,75,04,05,07,78,52,12,50,77,91,08},
                    {49,49,99,40,17,81,18,57,60,87,17,40,98,43,69,48,04,56,62,00},
                    {81,49,31,73,55,79,14,29,93,71,40,67,53,88,30,03,49,13,36,65},
                    {52,70,95,23,04,60,11,42,69,24,68,56,01,32,56,71,37,02,36,91},
                    {22,31,16,71,51,67,63,89,41,92,36,54,22,40,40,28,66,33,13,80},
                    {24,47,32,60,99,03,45,02,44,75,33,53,78,36,84,20,35,17,12,50},
                    {32,98,81,28,64,23,67,10,26,38,40,67,59,54,70,66,18,38,64,70},
                    {67,26,20,68,02,62,12,20,95,63,94,39,63,08,40,91,66,49,94,21},
                    {24,55,58,05,66,73,99,26,97,17,78,78,96,83,14,88,34,89,63,72},
                    {21,36,23,09,75,00,76,44,20,45,35,14,00,61,33,97,34,31,33,95},
                    {78,17,53,28,22,75,31,67,15,94,03,80,04,62,16,14,09,53,56,92},
                    {16,39,05,42,96,35,31,47,55,58,88,24,00,17,54,24,36,29,85,57},
                    {86,56,00,48,35,71,89,07,05,44,44,37,44,60,21,58,51,54,17,58},
                    {19,80,81,68,05,94,47,69,28,73,92,13,86,52,17,77,04,89,55,40},
                    {04,52,08,83,97,35,99,16,07,97,57,32,16,26,26,79,33,27,98,66},
                    {88,36,68,87,57,62,20,72,03,46,33,67,46,55,12,32,63,93,53,69},
                    {04,42,16,73,38,25,39,11,24,94,72,18,08,46,29,32,40,62,76,36},
                    {20,69,36,41,72,30,23,88,34,62,99,69,82,67,59,85,74,04,36,16},
                    {20,73,35,29,78,31,90,01,74,31,49,71,48,86,81,16,23,57,05,54},
                    {01,70,54,71,83,51,54,69,16,92,33,48,61,43,52,01,89,19,67,48}
                  };
```

I get the following error

```
q11.c:8:10: error: invalid digit "8" in octal constant
q11.c:8:67: error: invalid digit "8" in octal constant
q11.c:15:49: error: invalid digit "8" in octal constant
q11.c:17:19: error: invalid digit "9" in octal constant
q11.c:18:58: error: invalid digit "9" in octal constant
q11.c:22:16: error: invalid digit "8" in octal constant
q11.c:24:46: error: invalid digit "8" in octal constant
```

Comment: http://projecteuler.net/problem=11

Comment: An amusing historical detail is that in pre-K&R versions of C language spec ("C Reference Manual" era) it was OK to use 8 and 9 in octal constants. These digits preserved their decimal "weight" in the positional notation, i.e. 08 was the same value as 010 and 8, 090 was actually 0110 and 72 etc.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Don't prefix your numbers with `0`, unless you want them treated as octal, which clearly you don't.  So just use `8` instead of `08`.

If you're insistent on keeping everything properly aligned, even with single-digit numbers, just use spaces instead of zeros.

Comment: So, what's the solution? I want to store my phone number which is started with '0'.

Comment: Phone codes should not be stored as numeric types.  They don't behave like numbers. For example, leading zeroes are significant in phone codes, which is not true for numbers. Similarly it does not ever make sense to apply numeric operations to phone codes. Phone codes should always be stored as strings.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that you start some numbers with `0`, which means they are octal numbers (8-based)

Answer (score 8):

A number with a leading zero is taken to be octal by the compiler, so after that, digits greater than 7 trigger an error.

Answer (score 4):

In CPP octal number is started with 0 (zero), octals value are in the range 0-7, so 08 and 09 would always be unknown octal constant by the compiler, better to remove zero (prefixed) from 08 and 09.

Comment: @PascalCuoq yes and 'CPP' generally refers to the C preprocessor rather than C++, making this even more (slightly) confusing.