# error: invalid digit "8" in octal constant

Tags: c

i m learning c programming and i don't knonw what is going wrong with this program

the error code in the build message is

error: invalid digit "8" in octal constant.

can any one help please , and thank you =)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int ch ;
int codeS , codeH;
int ph = 1 , ad = 2 , lb = 3 , us = 4;

int main()

{

  //int ch ;

  printf("\n Bienvenue à SHCPahrma \n Veulleiz Choisir Votre Code Section \n ph : 1\t ad : 2\t lb : 3\t us : 4\t\n num secteur ");
  scanf("%d",&ch);
  printf("\n Entrer votre code secteur \t = ");
  scanf("%d",&codeS);
  printf("\n Entrer Code Horaire \t = ");
  scanf("%d",&codeH);




  // ch = 1223 ;
   //printf("%d",ch);
  if ((ch == 1) && (codeS == 1111) && (codeH == 0815))
    {
        printf("Bienvenue Mr le Pharmacien\n");
    }
    else if ((ch == 2) && (codeS == 2222) && (codeH == 0815))
    {
        printf("Bienvenue Mr l'Administrative\n");
    }
    else if ((ch == 3) && (codeS == 3333) && (codeH == 0717))
    {
        printf("Bienvenue Mr agent laboratoire\n");
    }

    else if ((ch == 4) && (codeS == 3333) && (codeH == 0717))
    {
        printf("Bienvenue Mr agent Usine \n");
    }

    else
    {
        printf("Accées Interdit veullier Contacter l'administration\n")
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ever encountered a '8' in octal number ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Whats wrong with array declaration: "invalid digit in octal constant"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459030/whats-wrong-with-array-declaration-invalid-digit-in-octal-constant)

Answer (score 6):

An integral literal starting with a `0` is *octal*, or base 8. That means that it can only contain digits [0-7]. If you want a decimal number, you must remove the leading `0`.