# Made an Inventory Program, don't know how to add totals in 'for' loop

Tags: c++

I am facing problem in my code, don't know how to add individual costs, to get `totalCost`, please help me in solving this.
I had applied a `for` loop to get cost and fixed the prices now i'm getting individual costs as I need but having problem in `totalCost`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Inventory
{
private:
    int itemNumber;
    int quantity;
    double cost;
    double totalCost;
public:
    Inventory()
    {
        itemNumber = 0;
        quantity = 0;
        cost = 0;
        totalCost = 0;
    }
    void data();
    double getdata();
    void display();
};

void Inventory :: data()
{
    cout << "Welcome to Waqar Milk Shop, we have varieties for your breakfast\n"
    << "Items available at our store are:\n"
    << "01. Eggs(Rs10/one)   02. Bread(Rs70/one)   03. Butter(Rs60/one)   04. Milk(Rs80/kg)"
    << "   05. Yogurt(Rs120/kg)\n"
    << "Please select anything you want, only press numeric code, Press 06 to exit\n\n";
}
double Inventory :: getdata()
{
    do
    {
        int i;
        cout << "how many items do you want to purchase?\n";
        cin >> i;
        for (int j=totalCost; j< i;j++)
        {
            cout << "Item:  ";  cin >> itemNumber;
            cout << "Quantity:  "; cin >> quantity;
            switch (itemNumber)
            {
                case 01: cost= 10*quantity; break;
                case 02: cost= 70*quantity;  break;
                case 03: cost= 60*quantity;  break;
                case 04: cost= 80*quantity;  break;
                case 05: cost= 120*quantity; break;
                default: cout << "Sorry this item does not exist";
            }
            cout << "Current bill is " << cost << endl;
        }   cost+=totalCost;
    } while (itemNumber==06);
}

void Inventory :: display()
{
    cout << "Your total bill is  Rs. " << cost << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Inventory a;
    a.data();
    a.getdata();
    a.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: next time add some comment to **line 54** because we dont see much linenumbers overhere...

Comment: okay i'll follow it

Answer (score 1):

There wasn't enough room in the comment field, but you need first to loop from zero to the number of elements:

```
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
```

Fortunately, `totalCost` actually holds zero at that point, so the code would operate without this change.

Next, you want to sum up in `totalCost`:

```
   cout << "Current bill is " << cost << endl;
   totalCost += cost;
}
```

Also, your `totalCost += cost` was outside the `for` loop, so I moved it inside.

Finally, you need to print the `totalCost`:

```
cout << "Your total bill is  Rs. " << totalCost << endl;
```

There may still be problems, including as I hinted a future [`08` compile error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8459030/1270789).

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks pretty good, you need to invert the sum at the end of the for loop, you are doing:

```
cost+=totalCost;
```

but it must be:

```
totalCost+=cost;
```

and dont forget to return **totalCost** in the `getData` method :)